# Create array in a function parameter in C

Tags: c++, c

Is this possible in C or C++? I have a function with the following declaration:

`int foo(double*)`

And I am trying to do something like this:

`foo([] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0});`

I know that I can create an array separately, but I am curious if I can do it that way.

Thanks.

Comment: What happened when you tried it ?

Comment: Syntax error. `syntax error : '='`, using VS 2012.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C: use C99 compound literals:

```
foo((double[]){ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 });
```

---

In C++: (I **hate** "C/C++" questions!) - I tried this and used C++11 initializer lists in a similar way. However, I'm not entirely confident whether this is legal or results in undefined behavior:

```
foo(&(std::vector<double> { 1, 2, 3, 4 })[0])
```

Anyone could confirm this? (compiles with no warnings, runs... that doesn't mean *anything,* though.)

Comment: There should be restriction not to tag same question with both C and C++ tag together.

Comment: @haccks [I was thinking about that today](https://twitter.com/H2CO3_iOS/status/409018644291534848)...

Comment: What a coincidence! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that by compound literals. C99 allows this feature.

```
  foo((double[]){1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0});
```

In this example, the compound literal creates an array (on the fly) containing the four `float`s.
You may also write this

```
  foo((double[4]){1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0});
```

Comment: The paranthesis don't match.

Comment: @piokuc; That's because I copied OP's code and did some changes to it instead of typing :)